# Intellisense naming of overload parameters when args are a conditional tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript 3.1 I've got a generic function whose arguments are either `(TInput, string)` or `(string)` depending on whether the generic's type parameter `TInput extends undefined`. Currently I'm using the new [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) feature to type the function's args as a conditional type of tuples:

```js
function test (
    ...args: TInput extends undefined ? [string] : [TInput, string]): void
)
```

This almost works perfectly. When I instantiate the generic function with a concrete type, VSCode only shows me the overload that applies to that generic type. Yay!

But there's one problem: Intellisense in VSCode reports the parameter names as `args_0` and `args_1` instead of more human-readable names like `input` for the generic parameter (if it's there) and `name` for the string parameter.

Is there any way to attach friendlier names to these parameters without losing the (correct) Intellisense for parameter count and type(s)?

BTW I'm OK with a solution that doesn't use tuples, as long as the core requirements work OK, which is: when the generic function is instantiated with a real type and I hover over the function in VSCode, I see the correct parameter count, name(s), and type(s) that are valid for that concrete type.

I tried adding overloads (see commented code below) but couldn't figure out how to get the overloads to compile. I got: *Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation. ts(2394)*

In an earlier iteration of this sample, I was able to use a type cast to get overloads to compile, but that in turn broke Intellisense for parameter count and types, where "broke" means that (unlike the code below) two overloads were always shown in Intellisense, even when the generic type parameter should have narrowed the list to a single valid overload.

```js
const makeTest = <TInput>() => {
//  Adding the overloads below doesn't work as expected. There are two problems: 
//    1. compiler error: "Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation. ts(2394)"
//    2. if I use a cast to get around the compile error, both overloads show in Intellisense regardless of TInput
//  function test (name: string): void; 
//  function test (input: TInput, name: string): void;
    function test (...args: TInput extends undefined ? [string] : [TInput, string]): void {
        // do stuff
    }
    return test;
}

// type inferred as: const f1: (args_0: string) => void
const f1 = makeTest<undefined>(); 

// type inferred as: const f2: (args_0: number, args_1: string) => void
const f2 = makeTest<number>();
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20makeTest%20%3D%20%3CTInput%3E()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20Adding%20the%20overloads%20below%20doesn't%20work%20as%20expected.%20There%20are%20two%20problems%3A%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%201.%20compiler%20error%3A%20%22Overload%20signature%20is%20not%20compatible%20with%20function%20implementation.%20ts(2394)%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%202.%20if%20I%20use%20a%20cast%20to%20get%20around%20the%20compile%20error%2C%20both%20overloads%20show%20in%20Intellisense%20regardless%20of%20TInput%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20function%20test%20(name%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20function%20test%20(input%3A%20TInput%2C%20name%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20test%20(...args%3A%20TInput%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20%5Bstring%5D%20%3A%20%5BTInput%2C%20string%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20test%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20inferred%20as%3A%20const%20f1%3A%20(args_0%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20makeTest%3Cundefined%3E()%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20inferred%20as%3A%20const%20f2%3A%20(args_0%3A%20number%2C%20args_1%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20makeTest%3Cnumber%3E()%3B) for this code so you can see the problem live.

BTW, I know I could make this easier by reversing the parameter order, but it's not practical to change its JS-facing signature. I only can change the TS typing at this point. Also, even if parameters were reversed, I really like how instantiating the generic with a specific type will remove the invalid overload, and I don't know if that would work with traditional optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just type assert the function to a conditional type dependent on `TInput`, that will give you the better intelisense you want. You can't easily specify the argument names for tuples in rest parameters:

```
const makeTest = <TInput>() => {

    function test (...args: [string] | [TInput, string]): void {
        // do stuff
    }
    return test as (TInput extends undefined ? ((name:string) => void) : ((input: TInput, name: string) => void);
}
```

Or a version with an implementation and a public signature for `makeTest`:

```
function makeTest<TInput>(): (TInput extends undefined ? ((name: string) => void) : ((input: TInput, name: string) => void))
function makeTest<TInput>(): ((name: string) => void) | ((input: TInput, name: string) => void) {

    function test(...args: [string] | [TInput, string]): void {
        // do stuff
    }
    return test;
}
```